# How do i run simple java program on JBoss?

Tags: java, jboss

I want to run a simple J2SE application in JBoss application server.
Is it possible to start? If Yes please let me know the procedure

Comment: Write a simple java program, deploy it and you're done...

Comment: @sinclair Thanks, my question is how do i run a class with main() method. For example i want to start a Telnet server using Java Code, how do i make that code run in JBoss?

Comment: JBoss is a Java EE application server. It runs servlets, and Java EE applications consisting of components such as EJBs. It does not run stand-alone Java programs with a `main` method.